# UITextField - can not input text. Keyboard does not responds

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, objective-c-2.0, uitextfielddelegate

I have UIViewController with UITextField in it.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextMemoViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> 

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textMemo;

@end
```

In implementation code is next:

```
#import "TextMemoViewController.h"

@implementation TextMemoViewController
@synthesize textMemo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.textMemo.delegate = self;


}
//.....
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return  YES;
}
```

The problem is, when i click on textField - keyboard appears, but nothing can be pressed on it. All Simulator hangs up. Text input is not possible with this behavior.

I have couple of some UIViewControllers with textFields and all is ok. But here, i can not find the reason why it happens.
I have cleaned DerivedData in Xcode, restarted all simulators and reset setting for them. Same situation on iphone.
Does anyone has ideas?

Comment: Have you checked whether the text field isn't nil when you try to input text? Is the super view big enough? I think text fields outside of the super view are shown, but do not react on input.

Comment: No, textField is not nil. Can rich breakpoint in 

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}
textField has it's address and values. The parent View is big. Only this one textField is present on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A better late, than never :)

Thanks all, but as i found a long time ago, the problem was in NOT resigned responder in some previous views.
In this case, view was covered by other one, but responder was not changed.

Maybe someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `UIAlertView` delegate.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  // DO NOT Create Other UIAlertView.
}
```

I think this is bug, on iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textMemo;
```

to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textMemo;
```

The difference is `strong` instead of `unsafe_unretained`. I believe your view is being unretained and that's why you aren't able to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//make sure you use this delegate and add all your textfields..
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
//  NSLog(@"Touches began called.");

//fill these in with all your textfields..
if([UserFirstName isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != UserFirstName){
    [UserFirstName resignFirstResponder];
}

}
```